# The correct phrase to describe a very small chance

Tags: word-choice

When describing a very small chance, such as 2%, which one(s) of the following is correct?

- Highly unlikely
- Highly impossible
- Highly improbable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Highly unlikely" and "Highly improbable" both work.  They don't have number values associated with them so whether a listener thinks you mean 10%, 2% or .001% depends on the listener's own thinking and the context.

"Highly impossible" doesn't make sense. Something is either possible or impossible. There is nothing in between.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. While I agree completely about the logic of possible and impossible, I'm aware that people modify **possible** and **impossible**  all the time (to hedge their bets) with words such as: **hardly/barely/scarcely/nearly/almost/virtually** and so on.

Comment: You are correct. I couldn't figure out how to explain such usages without resorting to tone of voice and facial expressions, which of course I can't type out as part of an answer.  If you can explain it clearly you can copy my answer and add your explanation, and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: I think that between us we have already covered the ground.